# Variables in Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Found this equation elsewhere on the internet:

$9^x - 9^{x- 1}  =  24$

I know intuitively that $x = 3/2$.

But how would I solve this with logarithms? ($9^x =  24$ and $9^{x- 1}  =  24$ I can do, but I'm stumped how to set this one up.  Nothing I've tried works)

Comment: hint $9^x-9^{x-1} = 9^{(x-1)+1}-9^{x-1} = 9^1\cdot 9^{x-1}-9^{x-1} = 9\cdot 9^{x-1}-1\cdot 9^{x-1}=(9-1)9^{x-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $9^x - 9^{x-1}  =  9^{x-1} \cdot (9-1)$
From there on it becomes easy.

$9^{x-1} = 3$
$9^{x-1} = 9^{\frac{1}{2}}$
$x-1 = \frac{1}{2}$ (this follows because the function $9^{x}$ is strictly increasing)
$x = \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: This doesn't help.  I don't follow how you got 9x−1⋅(9−1).  I would appreciate being shown how to do the problem step-by-step, with explanations if need be.  Frustrating to have an equation thrown out that I don't understand then told--"the rest is easy".

Comment: Do you know how much is $9^{x-1} \cdot 9? $ What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: Still lost.  How do I know that 9x−1=3?  Also, I don't understand where the 9 - 1 came from.

Comment: @Sail2DeepBlue How is it that you ''intuitively'' discovered the answer to be $\frac{3}{2}$, but fail to see how $9^{x-1}$ is a common factor for both of those terms?

Comment: Because the answer was provided on the website, and it was solved without the use of logarithms.  I get the answer.  It makes sense, but as I have just concluded a chapter on exponents and logarithms in a pre-calc book I'm working through, I wanted to know how to use logarithic methods here.  This particular problem is something I don't have in my particular book.  I understand how to do 9x^ = 24 and 9(x-1)^ = 24 using log or ln notation--just stumped on how to set this up.  Still new at this pre-calc thing, so no, I don't get how 9x-1 is a factor of 24.  Apologies.

Comment: @Sail2DeepBlue It's fine, I'm sorry for my rude comment. $9^{x-1} = 1\cdot 9^{x-1}$, and $9^x = 9\cdot 9^{x-1}$. Thus, $9^x - 9^{x-1} = 9^{x-1}(9 - 1)$. To verify this, you can expand the expression, and you will obtain your original expression. $9 - 1 = 8$, which is a factor of $24$, so you get $9^{x-1} = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$9^x - 9^{x-1} = 24 \implies 9^{x-1}(9 - 1) = 24 \implies 9^{x-1} = 3 \implies x = \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Okay, still stumped.  Where is the 9 - 1 coming from?  And how do I get from 24 to 3 (????).  Thank you.

Comment: PS:  as I asked how to do with logarithms, where are the log or ln indicators?

Comment: @Sail2DeepBlue We factored out $9^{x-1}$ from both $9^x$ and $9^{x-1}$, and this is where the $(9 - 1)$ comes from. The logarithm was done implicitly in the last step on the equation $9^{x-1} = 3$. To obtain $3$ from $24$, we divided both sides by $8$ (namely, $9 - 1$).

Comment: RE:  We factored out 9x−19x−1 from both 9x9x and 9x−19x−1, and this is where the (9−1)(9−1) comes from.

Comment: RE:  We factored out 9x−19x−1 from both 9x9x and 9x−19x−1, and this is where the (9−1)(9−1) comes from.  Okay.  A little clearer on somethings, if not everything.  I understand where the 1 (of the 9 - 1) comes from and how 24 reduced to 3.  Still not seeing how if I factor 9(x - 1)^ from 9x^ I get 9.  Apologies, again.  But I appreciate the help

Comment: $9^{x-1} \times 9 = 9^x$. You know that $9 \times 9 = 9^2$, and that $9^2 \times 9 = 9^3$, so you can extrapolate.

Comment: Oh!  Okay.  Well, I get that now.  Curious, when I first tried the problem I wondered if the 9 had to factored out from the 9x - 9x-1, but then that just seems to leave me 9( 1x^ - 1[x - 1]^), which, of course, seems useless . . .   I'll study this through a bit more to be sure I'm getting this.  2 questions--can this be set up with log or ln notation?  And how are you getting those very clear superscripts showing for your exponents typing into these boxes?  Thanks again--appreciate the help.  Apologies for initial terseness.

Comment: It's called LaTeX, you write it between \$\$. $9^{x-1}$ is \$9^{x-1}\$.

Comment: Thanks!  I shall remember that!  And since your last post, factoring $9^(x-1)$ from $9^x$ has become a little clearer still--I think.  Did it with actual numbers in place of the "x" value to see it concretely.  Could I think of this factoring as $9^x$ - $9^(x-1)$, with bases the same, as just "x - (x - 1)" = x - x + 1 = 1, so $9^1$ as the 9 in (9-1)?  Thanks again.

Comment: Didn't quite get the LaTex right.